# What's the relationship between coroutine and async IO?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, coroutine

I understand why the event loop is the core of async IO and why the coroutine allows better experience on developing with async IO. And I found coroutine libraries always have functions to start an event loop.

So, I wonder **what's the relationship between the coroutine and async IO**.

This is an obsecure description, so some specific questions are listed below for better explaining.

- Can the coroutine be used , however, without using async IO?
- Is the coroutine introduced on the basis of async IO?
- Is there a coroutine library lacking for async IO support?

Comment: Coroutines are well-suited for asynchronous actions (not just async I/O), but the relationship is not exclusive. You can use coroutines without async I/O (e.g., for generators) and async I/O without coroutines (using callbacks). Just like how recursion and trees work well together, but you can use recursion for things other than trees, and you can use coding techniques other than recursion for manipulating trees.